# Can't find installed package when running GitHub actions

Tags: python, django, github-actions

I'm trying to switch from Circle to GH actions and having an issue; I'm getting a `ModuleNotFoundError` when importing Django. I think the error is happening because I'm using a custom image; I'm using GH actions on other Django projects in almost exactly the same way without issues.

**ci.yml**

```yaml
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
    tags:
      - '**'
  pull_request: {}

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    container: tutorcruncher/tutorcruncher-test-image:py3.9
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:12
        ports:
        - 5432:5432
      redis:
        image: redis
        ports:
          - 6379:6379
        options: --entrypoint redis-server

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: set up python
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.9'

      - name: install dependencies
        run: |
          make install-test
          pip freeze
          python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --verbosity 0

      - run: make test
```

For reference, `make install test` simply calls `pip install -r requirements.txt` and `pip install -r requirements.test.txt`. When I run `pip freeze`, I can see all of my installed packages, including Django.

However, when `python manage.py collectstatic` runs, I get a ModuleNotFoundError:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/__w/MyProject/MyProject/manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'
```

Thanks in advance,
Tom

Comment: try instead to do `python -m pip install -r requirements.txt` I would hazard a guess that pip is not installing the packages to the correct place or maybe into the wrong python install

Comment: I agree with @JoranBeasley and the examples in the doc https://docs.github.com/en/actions/guides/building-and-testing-python#starting-with-the-python-workflow-template seem to always call pip using `python -m pip`

Comment: This was, in fact, the answer. Thanks.